# Pygame closing when using colliderect

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm trying to make it so that when the main character(mc) is touched by the spider, pygame closes.I don't have a strong understanding of pygame.Rect, but shouldn't this work? Somehow, pygame closes after adding this code anyways:

```
mcrect = mc.get_rect()
spirect = spider_small.get_rect()

if mcrect.colliderect(spirect):
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Whole code for reference:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math





#Initializing stuff and setting display settings
wait = time.sleep

print("What is your preferred screen width and height?(800,600 or greater.)")
wait(1)
print("If your chosen resolution is below 800,600 , you will be automatically set to 800,600")
wait(1)


preferred_screen_width = raw_input("Width?")
print("Dank MLG processing...")
wait(1.5)
preferred_screen_height = raw_input("Height?")
print("More dank MLG processing...")
wait(1.5)


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
from pygame.locals import *




'''Concepting







'''




sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('untitled.ogg')
sound.play(-1)

if int(preferred_screen_width) < 800:
    print("Illegal choice. Setting to 800,600")
    preferred_screen_width = 800
    preferred_screen_height = 600
elif int(preferred_screen_height) < 600:
    print("Illegal choice. Setting to 800,600")
    preferred_screen_width = 800
    preferred_screen_height = 600
else:
    print("Starting game")



#Ingame

pygame.display.set_caption("Spider Avoiderer")
spider_small = pygame.image.load("sag.png")

mc = pygame.image.load("mc.png")

mcrect = mc.get_rect()
spirect = spider_small.get_rect()

really_red = 255,0,0
dark_red = 171,0,0
deep_blue = 0,0,141
really_blue = 0,0,255
aa = raw_input("Would you like to use a custom background?(yes or no)")
if aa.lower() == "yes":
    print("Choose one of these colors(type exactly as written)")
    aaa = raw_input("really red, dark red, deep blue, really blue, or custom RGB")
    if aaa.lower() == "really red":
        penis = really_red
    elif aaa.lower() == "dark red":
        penis = dark_red
    elif aaa.lower() == "deep blue":
        penis = deep_blue
    elif aaa.lower() == "really blue":
        penis = really_blue
    elif aaa.lower() == "custom rgb":
        print("Enter your RGB coloring:")
        rgb_red = raw_input("Value of red? ")
        rgb_green = raw_input("Value of green? ")
        rgb_blue = raw_input("Value of blue?")
        penis = int(rgb_red),int(rgb_green),int(rgb_blue)
elif aa.lower() == "no":
    penis = 100,210,25
else:
    penis = 100,210,25


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((int(preferred_screen_width),int(preferred_screen_height)))
#fps
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(30)


background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((penis))


mc_x = 20
mc_y = 20
spider_x = 600
spider_y = 600


#Main loop
while True:

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(spider_small,(spider_x,spider_y))
    screen.blit(mc,(mc_x,mc_y))
    if mc_x > spider_x:
        spider_x  += .8
    if mc_x < spider_x:
        spider_x -= .8

    if  mc_y > spider_y:


        spider_y += .8

    if mc_y<spider_y:
        spider_y -= .8
    wait(1)







    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    if  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        mc_x -= 3


    elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        mc_x += 3

    elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        mc_y -= 3

    elif  pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        mc_y += 3






    pygame.display.update()
    if mcrect.colliderect(spirect):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `Rect` with the `get_rect()` function of a `Surface`, the `topleft` property of the `Rect` will always be `0, 0`.

Since you never change `mcrect` and `spirect`, they always overlap, since they both have the same position (`0, 0`); so `mcrect.colliderect(spirect)` will always be `True`.

---

What you  should do is to get rid of the `mc_x`, `mc_y`, `spider_x` and `spider_y` variables and use `mcrect` and `spirect` to keep track of the position of your images, e.g. instead of

```
mcrect = mc.get_rect()
...
screen.blit(mc,(mc_x,mc_y))
...
mc_y += 3
```

do

```
mcrect = mc.get_rect(top=20, left=20)
...
screen.blit(mc, mcrect)
...
mcrect.move_ip(0, 3)
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem. I'm trying to redo the movement for the spider, and am trying this: if mcrect(top) > spirect(top): spirect.move_ip(-3,0)     but it is not working? I also tried if mcrect[3] > spirect[3]:
        spirect.move_ip(-3,0)     and  if mcrect[0] > spirect[0]:
        spirect.move_ip(-3,0)

Comment: I think you're looking for `if mcrect.left < spirect.left:`  and/or `if mcrect.top < spirect.top:`

Comment: For some reason the spider isn't showing on the screen. I'll have to fix that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ensure that you use the right `Rect` in the `blitt` call. Maybe but a `print spirect` in your main loop to check if the rect is actually on the screen.

Comment: This is my blit statement  screen.blit(spider_small,(spirect)) along with one of my if statements for the movement     if mcrect.top > spirect.top:
        spirect.move_ip(3,0) Still can't figure it out.